# Pool в unity, что это такое?

Tags: c#, unity3d, pool

Объясните пожалуйста, что такое pool в unity и желательно посоветуйте ресурс для их изучения.

Comment: Если вам легче смотреть, чем читать, можете посмотреть это [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3v_9NZ4nBg0). А вообще советую почитать вот это: [Как задать хороший вопрос? ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), там первое слово - изучайте, то есть нужно погуглить самому. Неужели вы сами не пытались вбить "Пул объектов unity" в поисковик?

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно посмотрю и это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если имеется ввиду пул объектов, то тут понятно расписано. [https://riptutorial.com/ru/unity3d/example/7471/пул-объектов](https://riptutorial.com/ru/unity3d/example/7471/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Если вы делаете игру, в которой нужно будет создавать много одинаковых объектов (например пули), то это может сильно замедлить ваш проект.

При использовании pool объекты не удаляются, а деактивируются. Новые объекты не создаются, будут активироваться объекты из pool, чтобы не замедлять работу.

Comment: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), пункт "являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт"

Comment: @Jack_oS всмысле лишь ссылкой? Ответ в виде лишь ссылки выглядит так: `посмотрите тут: https:..`, а в этом ответе дано описание, почему плохо создавать много объектов вручную `это может сильно замедлить ваш проект.`, описан принцип пула `...не удаляются, а деактивируются. Новые <...> не создаются`. Разумеется в ответе не будет полных скриптов для пула, потому что они отличаются. Если @mksmptrnk прочитав ответ, решит изучить тему дальше, то он это сделает.

Comment: @МаксимФисман wow... easy man )) мой комментарий был сделан до правки ответа

Comment: @Jack_oS Не заметил, сорри